# Visual Studio debugging: Still getting “The breakpoint will not currently be hit...” after building project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, location, breakpoints

Most of the time, when I build my project, I'm able to attach to breakpoints and debug, as I should. However, sometimes after building, I still get the error “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version.” No matter how many times I build and rebuild it doesn't change it, until seemingly randomly it decides to behave and start working again. How can I fix this when it happens?

Edit: My builds are fine, there are no errors in my builds.

Comment: Check if any process is still keeping your assembly loaded (IIS Express), Clean Solution, Rebuil Solution

Comment: I've tried everything. I did iisret, build solution, rebuilt solution, restarted my computer.

Comment: What type of project is it?

Comment: ASP.Net Webforms project

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess...

In "Solution Property Pages" -> "Project Dependencies", choose the project and make sure the dependencies are defined well; for example: if you are using a web service in another project in the same solution, you should make the project including the web service depending on your project or you will not be able to debug the web service.

Of course, I don't know how this option may be bypassed as you say it happens to you randomly.